# How To Free Allocated Memory From Another Function

Tags: c, function, pointers, char, free

I wrote the following code today to experiment with returning pointers to allocated memory.
The program works fine but I do have a few questions:

1. To allocate the memory for the return value of `rmch` I use `realloc`. I understand the function and what it does for the most part I'm just quite not sure what the point of `(char *)` in the line `ret = (char *) realloc(ret, c * sizeof(char));` I understand that `realloc(ret, c * sizeof(char));` resizes the allocated memory to #c chars, but what does the `(char *)` part do?
2. I do not free the allocated memory that `ret` points to anywhere, but I do free a pointer to `ret` which is called in my `main` function. What is happening to the allocated memory? If it is not being freed how would I go about freeing it?

Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char* rmch(char *str, char ch)
{
    char *ret = NULL;
    int c = 0, i;

    for(i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if(str[i] != ch)
        {
            c++;
            ret = (char *) realloc(ret, c * sizeof(char));
            ret[c - 1] = str[i];
        }
    }
    ret[c] = '\0';
    return ret;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *foo = rmch("f o o", ' ');

    printf("%s", foo);
    free(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `ret = (char *) realloc(ret, c * sizeof(char));` the `(char *)` casts the `void*` returned by `realloc` to a `char*`. It's required by C++, so people who write lots of C++ tend to cast the return value of `malloc` and friends. It's pointless and widely discouraged in C.

Comment: You better remove the `(char *)` you don't understand. It's a typecast (google it!), but its use is discouraged with memory management functions. Also google 'why not cast the return value of malloc()'.

Comment: Ah so that's how you accept answers, thank you all very much; at the moment it says I must wait ~4 minutes to accept an answer so I will when that time comes; thanks.

Comment: BTW, `sizeof(char)` is `1` by standard. So, `c * sizeof(char)` is equivalent to `c`.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Actually, using `malloc` in C++ is widely discouraged.

Comment: @Jack, while it is defined in the standard, it is never a bad idea to explicitly say, this is going to be storing char values, and I need this many, rather than just allocating some number of bytes.

Comment: @ardentsonata: `char *foo = malloc(10);` already explicitly says that it's going to store `char` values. :)

Comment: @netcoder, Ah, but in different standards of C, you can't just willy-nilly do assignments and defines in-line. Thus, it could lead to some ambiguity. Also, that is not always the case. I could use an 8-bit int/long to store addresses that malloc returns as well, it all depends on the program constructs provided to me.

Comment: @ardentsonata: IMHO, unless otherwise stated (i.e.: ANSI C, or M$ C), there's no reason to refer to a 20+ years old standard that has been superseded many times since. Also, you cannot safely store addresses that malloc returns in an 8-bit integer if your architecture has memory addresses beyond this range. It actually depends on the *platform*. More generally, you'd want to address `char` values from a `char*`, and `int` values from an `int*`. If you do otherwise, and I believe it's wrong to, then maybe you need the explicit `sizeof(char)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Freeing Foo in main will free the ret you've realloc'd in rmch.

The reason being is free() goes to the address specified by the pointer which is returned by rmch.

Also, as you have tagged this post with the "C" tag, you should never cast the return value of allocations. `void *'s` are automagically, implicitly promoted to whatever they are stored in, provided they were given the correct byte sizes during allocation.

As an aside, you should never directly store any allocated memory directly into the pointer you are using/will be using as this can lead to memory leaks if the pointer returned is NULL and you were still pointing to old memory.

Better to do this:

```
temp = realloc();
if( temp == NULL)
{
     printf("realloc failed to reallocated memory!");
     return NULL;
}
ret = temp;
```

And then you would need to check for a NULL return in your main as well.

Answer (score 1):

Still one more problem on your code, when you run it with valgrind, you got something like this:

```
toc@UnixServer:~$valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes ./realloc_pb
==17077== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==17077== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==17077== Using Valgrind-3.6.1-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==17077== Command: ./realloc_pb
==17077== 
==17077== Invalid write of size 1
==17077==    at 0x80484BF: rmch (realloc_pb.c:19)
==17077==    by 0x80484E3: main (realloc_pb.c:25)
==17077==  Address 0x41b709b is 0 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==17077==    at 0x402896C: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525)
==17077==    by 0x804848A: rmch (realloc_pb.c:14)
==17077==    by 0x80484E3: main (realloc_pb.c:25)
==17077== 
==17077== Invalid read of size 1
==17077==    at 0x402903D: __GI_strlen (mc_replace_strmem.c:284)
==17077==    by 0x4098739: puts (ioputs.c:37)
==17077==    by 0x4050112: (below main) (libc-start.c:226)
==17077==  Address 0x41b709b is 0 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==17077==    at 0x402896C: realloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:525)
==17077==    by 0x804848A: rmch (realloc_pb.c:14)
==17077==    by 0x80484E3: main (realloc_pb.c:25)
==17077== 
foo
==17077== 
==17077== HEAP SUMMARY:
==17077==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17077==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 6 bytes allocated
==17077== 
==17077== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==17077== 
==17077== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==17077== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 11 from 6)
```

Cause you need to allocate more room for the null terminated char, so modify this also:

```
temp = (char *) realloc(ret, (c + 1) * sizeof(char)); // It's better to use temp pointer as suggested by ardent sonata
```

The last thing is about the casting malloc or realloc functions it's not really necessary, it's useful for the compiler in case you forgot to add the correct header (stdlib.h), so he can warn you (http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html).

Hope this help.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` or `calloc` will allocate the memory for the size you mentioned. `realloc` will resize the already allocated memory, either it can shrink or expand the existing heap buffer.

For example If we are expanding the existing heap buffer from `n` bytes to `n+1` bytes 
means we have to call realloc like `realloc(existing_bufPtr, n+1)`. Now OS has to increase the existing buffer by one bytes, so it will check if `n+1`th byte from `existing_bufPtr` is unallocated to any other purpose. If So it will just expand the size of the existing buffer to `n+1` or else it will allocates new buffer in separate place and it will move the values from the existing buffer to the new buffer. And then it will return starting address of the newly allocated buffer.

So we have to do a check whether the return address is same as what we passed if its not same we have to free the previous buffer. So change your code as below

```
if(str[i] != ch)
{
   c++;
   ret_new = (char *) realloc(ret, c * sizeof(char));
   if (NULL == ret_new)     
   {
       return NULL;
   }
   else if (ret_new != ret)
   {
       free(ret);
       ret = ret_new;
   }

   ret[c - 1] = str[i];
}
```

Shrinking the existing heap buffer using `realloc` will not return the new addres. But expanding may return new address.

`realloc` will return the pointer type as `void *`, we have to type case it to our type of pointer `char *`.

Memory allocation function (`malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`) is always a costly operation for an operating system. So Instead of calling `realloc` for `n` times, allocate memory only once using `malloc(sizeof(str))`, so that performance will be good.